# Where are the specifications/XSDs for Amazon MWS feed XML processing reports?

Tags: amazon-mws

Amazon provides a batch of documents describing the format of the feeds we can send via MWS, however, we also need to know what to expect in their responses, what status codes may be reported or what is the structure of XML when errors reported, etc...

Where can I get the information?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The MWS XML schemata are documented within the *Selling on Amazon Guide to XML* linked from the *Developer Guides* section in the [Amazon Marketplace Web Service (Amazon MWS) Documentation](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/docs.html).

I'm omitting a direct link to the PDF, as this might change once in a while. For the same reason the XSD files you are looking for are not publicly linked by Amazon as well, rather you'll find the links to the most current schema documents within the respective sections of the *Selling on Amazon Guide to XML*.

You might also be interested in the *Amazon MWS Developer Guide*, the *Feeds API Reference* and the guide for the [Amazon MWS Scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html), which are all available there as well.

Good luck!

Comment: In the API References you can find links to the XSDs. For the Feeds API this is the current Url: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a rather old question but I just wanted to look at the actual XML schema files myself today.

There is an [XML Documentation PDF](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf) hosted on `images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com` which I assume will stay there for a while. This PDF contains links to the core schema files [amzn-envelope.xsd](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/amzn-envelope.xsd), [amzn-header.xsd](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/amzn-header.xsd), and [amzn-base.xsd](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/amzn-base.xsd) and some other API schemas like [Product.xsd](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/Product.xsd) which all appear to be relative to `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/`.

The PDF explicitly states that

> The XSD samples shown on the Help pages may not reflect the latest XSDs. We recommend 
>   using the provided XSD links to obtain the latest [ve]rsions.

However, the [official MWS Feeds API documentation](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html) also links to some XSDs but these are relative to `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/`**`release_4_1`**`/` now, e.g. [Price.xsd](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/Price.xsd). Schema references also seem to be relative to this path. For example, Price.xsd includes amzn-base.xsd via `<xsd:include schemaLocation="amzn-base.xsd"/>` and sure enough [there it is](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/amzn-base.xsd).

Unfortunately, I have no idea whether `release_4_1` is the latest release of the schemas but the link from the MWS API documentation is a good indicator to me.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get the XSD's which I think is the most "official" way is to go to your [Seller Central](https://sellercentral.amazon.com) and navigate to Help > XML & data exchange > Reference > XSDs.
There you can download all the XSD's available to your account. 
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this **XSD files are outdated**.

Just checked the official sellercentral help page for the XSD files https://sellercentral-europe.amazon.com/gp/help/G1611
For the OrderReport there is still **release_4_1** referenced.

Some time ago amazon has added a new field to [OrderReport](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/OrderReport.xsd) for EU markets. The new field is `IsSoldByAB`.
I am using the xsd files since many years for automatic code generation. And this fails from time to time because of new fields like this. This field is not descriped in one of this:

- **release_1_9** ($Revision: #7 $, $Date: 2006/05/23 $)
- **release_4_1** ($Revision: #10 $, $Date: 2007/09/06 $)

XSD files and I am not able to find a version that include this field.

Since some years I extend the XSD file on my own to generate my code. `IsSoldByAB` is just a boolean field as `IsPrime` or `IsBusinessOrder`. So this was an easy task but not "official"...

Comment: Official sellercentral help page for XSD files now doesn't reference anything anymore :/